# Selective C# code generation (SOAP)

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, cisco-axl

I'm using cisco unified communications manager API (AXL) which is very huge. Generated God object with 350k+ lines of code takes 30+ seconds to initialize in runtime. I used to cut redundant methods and properties and it really helps. I'm looking for tool to automate selective C# code generation, or maybe I should write my own?

Comment: How are you generating the C#?  "Add service reference" in VS or svcutil.exe from the command line?

Comment: I tried wsdl.exe and cmdline svcutil

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found two comfortable tools to edit soap schema. Using them allows me to remove redundant methods and messages relatively fast and I can run wsdl/svcutil after cleaning.

Tools appraised by my own marks:

- SoapUI (pro version only) [3/5]
- Altova Xmlspy [4/5]

Unfortunately both tools are not free, and both don't allow to select multiple items to delete (should carefully spam "delete" button (in soap UI this is not keyboard button ;))).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a tool like Notepad++ that can handle large files easily and just copy and past the methods/classes you need after the large C# file is generated. That way it's free, no xml or software to learn and you can always just open the C# file and grab any code when it's needed.